# DATE is not getting updated into database using sql command

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to update the date in database which at the begining is set to null, and the datatype used for date are `nvarchar(50)`.

I've even tried `nchar`, `date`, `varchar(50)` datatypes in SQL Server but when updating it gives me error saying:

> *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

How do I get rid of this and I want to disaply date in format 2-feb-2013 using

```
dd.tostring("D);
```

and it is not working.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update barcode set intime=@time,date='@date' where bcd=@bcd", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cc", SqlDbType.NChar, 20).Value = c;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@bcd", SqlDbType.NChar, 20, "bcd").Value = textBox1.Text;
DateTime dd = DateTime.Now;

String ss, sss;
ss = dd.ToString("t");
sss = dd.ToString("d");

cmd.Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "intime").Value = ss;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date, 50, "date").Value = sss;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Seriously, how the hell can this be edited **three** times and still not be close to being correct?

Comment: @Anthony some folks make very minor edits to things like the title and ignore the rest of the post. :-(

Comment: ss,sss,cc,dd? I'd recommend you to pick more suitable names for your variables

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't see why you want to use string parameters for this, or why you care about format before sending date and time values to the database. In any case, since SQL Server can also tell time, why make the app do this at all? You can bypass all of this by setting a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for both the `intime` and `date` columns (so you don't need to even specify them when inserting), and when updating, if in fact you do need to update those columns:

```
UPDATE dbo.barcode 
  SET intime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      [date] = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  WHERE bcd = @bcd;
```

Answer (score 0):

because you wrap the `@date` with single quotes. Parameters shouldn't be wrap with single quotes. Remove it and it will work.

```
UPDATE barcode 
SET    intime = @time,
       date = @date 
WHERE  bcd = @bcd
```

one more thing, leave the format of the date as is. Only convert the date during projection (*select*)

Comment: wil i get the format as i mentioned before just by using date datatype?

Comment: @YuviM no. Dates should be save as date on the database. If you want the date to be formatted, do it on `SELECT` statements or on the application level. You will have a hard time on searching or manipulating dates if you have this format: `2-feb-2013` because it you will use `varchar` for that. The format of date on the database doesn't matter at all because clients will not be looking on the database. They're interested on the application.

Comment: i have prepared a login and logout form so its necessary for me to format date

Comment: question, what's the data type of the date column in your table?

Comment: then pass the variable `dd` on the value of the paramater `cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date, 50, "@date").Value = dd;`